# Can I initialize an object with a function returning a ValueTuple?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I'd like to initialize an object with a ValueTuple like this:

```
var m = new SearchResultViewModel
{
     (Elements, SomeNumber) = this.SearchResultItems()
};

private (List<string> a, int b) SearchResultItems()
{
    [...]
    return (list, 1024);
}
```

Where

```
public class SearchResultViewModel
{
    public IList<string> Elements { get; set; }

    public long SomeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Is sth like this (or similar) possible**? Compiller gives me a bunch of errors:
Cannot initialize type 'SearchResultViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable', 
Invalid initializer member declarator, 
The name 'Elements' does not exist in the current context,
The name 'SomeNumber' does not exist in the current context,

While this code works OK:

```
var m = new SearchResultViewModel();
(m.Elements, m.SomeNumber) = this.SearchResultItems();
```

Also this compiles OK (but I wouldn't like to call the function twice):

```
var m = new SearchResultViewModel()
{
   Elements = this.SearchResultItems().Item1,
   SomeNumber = this.SearchResultItems().Item2
};
```

Comment: It's not possible, you'll need to create ValueTuple single property in your ViewModel

Comment: Thank you very much, MistyK.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do something like that you could use a conversion operator.

```
public class SearchResultViewModel
  {
    public IList<string> Elements { get; set; }
    public long SomeNumber { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator SearchResultViewModel((List<string> elements, int someNumber) tuple)
    {
      return new SearchResultViewModel()
      {
        Elements = tuple.elements,
        SomeNumber = tuple.someNumber
      };
    }
  }
```

Now it's possible to do the following:

```
var m = SearchResultItems() as SearchResultViewModel;
```

Although this solution works, personally i'm not a fan. Casting a ValueTuple this way, seems wrong. But that's my opinion.

Comment: Why are you using an explicit operator over just a constructor?

Comment: I make it a rule to only make constructors that are really necessary.
Example: If a class has some required fields, put them in the constructor to make that clear.
I never make a constructor to match the specific outcome of a method outside the classes (like the sample method of the OP).
Because of that, I didn't event think of the possibility of using a constructor.
But you are right, It would work as well.

In my opinion, SearchResultItems() should already return a SearchResultViewModel. If you have a class to contain the data, why not use it as the result of the method, if possible.